# iAd doesn't work

Tags: ios, iad

My app just uploaded to the app store and for the first time I put an iAd banner on it. When I run the app on the simulator it worked fine and showed the sample iAd version that runs on the simulator.

So I just downloaded my app from the app store and saw that the iAd doesn't load and the iAd banner is totally white.

I didn't know that I have to do some tax and bank account set up on itunes connect so I just set up my tax and bank account and they are now approved and processed, but the iAd banner is still white.

I was wondering if I'm missing anything and if there is anything else I need to do.

Thanks you all,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, even if you have done everything right, you still can have no ads from the iAd network.

Apple has some criteria to decide which apps will get ads and which ads they will get. So, You should wait until you have enough users and Apple reserves ads to your app.

In the meanwhile, you can try to load ads from other networks if iAds fail. With a quick google search can even find services that do that automatically for you.

Comment: so should I remove the iAd banner for now?